# Find lines from number of characters

Tags: find, notepad++, line

Hello all i have a file with 71989 lines in notepad++, most of the lines have 11 commas (,) because i have 11 columns but when i load my file in SQL i get some errors because some lines have 9 records, so 9 commas.
Is there a way in notepad++ to find which lines have 9 commas instead of 11?

I can also use python.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using Python you could count all occurrences of a comma on each line...

```
'''

contents of data.txt (your SQL file for example)...

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,
,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,

Note: Nine commas on the third and fifth lines.

'''

with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    
for line_number, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
    if line.count(',') == 9:
        print('Check line number: ' + str(line_number))
```

Outputs:

```
Check line number: 3
Check line number: 5
```

Maybe that helps :o?

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^,]*(?:,[^,]*){9}$`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- Check `Bookmark line`
- <kbd>Find all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    [^,]*       # 0 or more non comma
    (?:         # start non capture group
        ,           # a comma
        [^,]*       # 0 or more non comma
    ){9}        # end group, must appear 9 times
$           # end of line
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]